# Django - Why is this random text rendering when I get errors upon form submission attempt?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have a page with a form that takes in an employee # (using foreignkey), and when it is submitted it verifies that this employee # is in fact in another model (Salesman), and checks if 'WF' is in the *team* field for this employee. While the logic works and everything is being displayed, I keep getting this random bold text under the box **Salesman object (406)** (or whichever number I entered that would give me an error) after submitting the form, along with the proper error on top.

[image]

I think this is related to the foreignkey field part, but I'm not sure how to prevent this from showing up when there are errors.

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_number
```

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')

    def clean_employee_number(self):
        employee_number = self.cleaned_data.get('employee_number')

        if 'WF' in employee_number.team:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Employee not valid, please contact manager")
        else:
            pass
        return self.cleaned_data
```

**views.py**

```
class EnterExitArea(CreateView):
    model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    template_name = "operations/enter_exit_area.html"
    form_class = WarehouseForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        emp_num = form.cleaned_data['employee_number']
        area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
        station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']

        if 'enter_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter((Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(work_area=area) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_in__isnull=True)) & (Q(station_number=station) | Q(station_number__isnull=True))).update(time_in=datetime.now())
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

        elif 'leave_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div>
            <div style="color: red">{{ form.employee_number.errors.as_text }}</div>
            <div>
                <label>Employee</label>
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>
       <!-- ... More fields ... -->
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
                <button type="submit" name="leave_area" value="Leave">Leave Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock main %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is part of the `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` widget and it's the representation of the selected object (the Salesman object with ID 406).

If you wanted to get rid of it you would have to create a new widget which extends `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` and removes that bit from the template. Here you can see how [`ForeignKeyRawIdWidget`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.7/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L125) and its [template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.7/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/widgets/foreign_key_raw_id.html) look like.

Alternatively, and possibly better, you could consider to define the `__str__` method of the `Salesman` model to show something more meaningful, in the same way you did for `EmployeeWorkAreaLog`.